# How to change color on selected index change of dropdown inside angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

In my angular material table there are two dropdowns whose OnChange method gives an output of **YES/NO**. Now, what i want is, if both the selected indexes are **NO**, then the color of the selected index will be getting changed into **RED**.

Below is my HTML :

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Eligible To Vote?">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Eligible To Vote? </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field [class.app-input-no-underline]="true">
        <mat-select id="eligind" placeholder="Select" 
              (ngModelChange)="EligOnChange($event)" 
              [(value)]="element?.detail.Elig_Indc"
         [(ngModel)]="element?.detail.Elig_Indc">

         <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="0">No</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Voting?">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Voting? </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field [class.app-input-no-underline]="true">
        <mat-select id="voting" placeholder="Select" (ngModelChange)="VoteOnChange($event)" 
        [(value)]="element?.detail.Voting_Indc " 
        [(ngModel)]="element?.detail.Voting_Indc" name="voting" >
          <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="1" >Yes</mat-option>
          <mat-option  value="0">No</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

And below is my OnChange code for the dropdown:

```
EligOnChange($event, element) {
 if ($event !== 0) {
   this.EligibilityToVote = false;
  } else {
     this.EligibilityToVote = true;
  }
  return this.EligibilityToVote;
  }

 `VoteOnChange($event, element) {
      if ($event !== 0) {
      this.IsVoting = false;
        } else {
       this.IsVoting = true;
      }
     return this.IsVoting;
   }`
```

Now, depending on the output of both the methods, i want to change the color of both the selected index to RED

if both the selected index gives answer as NO: then the text will become red in color. That is all i want

**Please feel free to ask any question**

**Thanks in advance**

**EDIT**

The [stackblitz URL](https://angular-yjnjta.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: What data you are displaying in dropdown? Is it an array of object? Can you show that code?

Comment: ` <mat-option>Select</mat-option> <mat-option value="1" >Yes</mat-option><mat-option value="0">No</mat-option></mat-select>`

Comment: It is static data on html

Comment: How you get that data in component. I need to see that code

Comment: @DheerajKumar the ngModelChange listener is used to get the data into the component

Comment: i have some code on ngOninit....that is generating the code

Answer (score 1):

Use `[ngClass]` to add a css class to both indices.

Create a class in your components css

```
.red {
    color: red;
    [..]
}
```

Use `[ngClass]="{'red': bothInvalid}"` where ever you want to apply the styles
and in your component a method

```
get bothInvalid() {
    // true of both are false
    return !this.IsVoting && !this.EligibilityToVote;
}
```

Comment: In which tag in material table shall i add `[ngClass]="{'red': bothInvalid}"`...this particular tag ?

Comment: The class which i need to change is in the main style file..
.`.mat-select-value-text {
  font-size: 13px!important;
  color: #666666!important;
  font-weight: lighter!important;
}`

Comment: How can i overwrite the the color conditionally?

Comment: It depens where you want the color to show up? Try applying it to where that css class you showed is used and also use !important in your `red` class. Not 100% sure if mat components support ngClass just now, if not it may become more difficult. Else create a stackblitz, that would make helping easier.

Comment: It si almost similar to this link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvvd2a?file=app%2Fselect-panel-class-example.html)

Comment: In my case the selected text will be having a font-color of red, rather than on display panel color to be that

Comment: I cannot provide anything else...max i can provide you the snapshot of the table @Fussel

Comment: As this is about styles an example with some static data would be absolutly fine.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhxdfy-ntohup?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html

Comment: What i want is if  both the selected index are same, then the color would change to red...and both the dropdown is in material table

Comment: Only made it [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhxdfy-6z6b2f) far... not quite as it should be, maybe I can get to it later again.

Comment: Thanks buddy...even i am searching

Comment: [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjnjta?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage ngClass directive here

```
[ngClass]="getColor()"
```

Inside your code you can dynamically add css classes to it as follows,

```
getColor() {

     let classes = {
      'red' : !this.IsVoting && !this.EligibilityToVote,
      'green' : !this.IsVoting && this.EligibilityToVote,
      'blue' : this.IsVoting && !this.EligibilityToVote,
       ...
     };

    return classes;
}
```

You can have single or multiple classes as a true. Value true will add the class to the DOM element.